# Autoplay Embedded Youtube Video and NOT Display Suggested Video After Playing The Video

Tags: video, youtube, autoplay

I am trying to auto play an embedded Youtube Video and also NOT dipsplay the suggested videos after playing the video. I used the code below but it is not not working the way i wanted it to work.

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d0svOaz4Jcs?autoplay=1?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I will appreciate a better insight on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d0svOaz4Jcs?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

With `?rel=0&autoplay=1` instead `?autoplay=1?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0`